# Enum or typedef with types

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'd like to create a simple object that I can access like this:

```
myobject.floatValue1 = 1.0;
myobject.floatValue2 = 2.0;
```

It shouldn't have anymore than the two properties.  Is it possible to create an enum or typedef with such a simple structure. Or must I create a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just make a C structure:

```
struct myStruct 
{
    float floatValue1;
    float floatValue2;
};
typedef struct myStruct myType;
```

Then use it like this:

```
myType myVariable = {0.0, 0.0}; // optional initialization
myVariable.floatValue1 = 1.0;
myVariable.floatValue2 = 2.0;
```

Comment: I get this error I do myType.floatValue1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '.' token

Comment: did you define a variable like "myType variableName;" and then do "variableName.floatValue1 = 1.0f"?  Remember, it's a new type, not a variable itself...

Comment: @4thSpace, be careful - without the `typedef` that line declares a variable called `myType`, which is a little strange.  I edited my answer to show a more expected sort of use case.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using a `struct`, e.g.:

```
struct MyObjectType {
    float floatValue1;
    float floatValue2;
};

...

MyObjectType myobject;
myobject.floatValue1 = 1.0;
myobject.floatValue2 = 2.0;
```

Comment: You'd have to reference it as `struct MyObjectType myobject`, or typedef it as per Carl Norum's reply.